# Construct nested object graph from SQL hasmany relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Example: I have some `articles` and `comments` and I want to get something like this:

```
[{
   title: "Article 1",
   content: "Super long article goes here",
   comments: [
      { author: "Troll", message: "You suck, Sir!" }, 
      { author: "SpamBot", message: "http://superawesomething.com/"}
   ]
},{
   title: "Article 2",
   content: "Another long article goes here",
   comments: [ ... ]
}]
```

Right now I see two solutions:

1. Get the articles first, then the comments in a second query with some `IN` condition and finally add the comments to the respective articles.
2. Good old joins. For one I will still have to fiddle around with the data a lot to get into the structure I want. But beyond that I'm a little concerned since payload like `articles.content` will be transmitted for every comment - unless there is a way to do the join I am not aware of.

I'm hoping that my SQL-illiteracy makes me miss the simple solution.

Comment: I can't speak for postgresql, but MySQL is pretty horrible for dealing  with hierarchical data.

Nothing wrong with the first method you list there. Would probably be the way I would go.

Comment: @invertedSpear: Seems the best approach, unless complete read consistency is important. Since the problem does not seem particularly exotic to me, I was hoping that some RDBMS might actually solve it.

Comment: Pretty sure SQLServer is your answer for hierarchical data. I think TSQL has some pretty good functions for dealing with it, but depending on your applications SQL drivers, you may find you are still dealing with that larger payload in the content column.

Comment: @invertedSpear: Postgres can do hierarchical queries just as good as SQL Server (although I don't see them needed here) - plus Postgres has native JSON support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this, using aggregates and/or subqueries. Something like:

```
select title, content, json_agg(comments.author, comments.message) as comments
from articles 
join comments on articles.article_id = comments.article_id
group by article_id;
```

If you need this aggregated into one string/json/something - just wrap it into another aggregate query like this:

```
select json_agg(sub)
from (
  select title, content, json_agg(comments.author, comments.message) as comments
  from articles 
  join comments on articles.article_id = comments.article_id
  group by article_id) sub;
```

This is a Postgres query. Have no expirience with Mysql.

Comment: You might want to add that `json_agg` is a new function introduced in the just released 9.3 version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but it still can be emulated with `array_agg` or `string_agg` in the earlier versions.

Comment: I also think you need `json_agg(comments)` as the function expects a record, not two scalar values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `json_agg(comments)` will aggregate all fields of `comments`. Can not test it now, but I saw some examples with such calls to `json_agg`. If it doesnt work - combine them into one record with record constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a viable solution. Seems like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` can be used as `STRING_AGG` and everything else can be implemented on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a MySQL solution:

```
SELECT CONCAT( '[ { '
              ,GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'title: "', REPLACE( a.title, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                    ,', contents: "', REPLACE( a.content, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                    ,', comments: ', a.comments
                                   )
                             SEPARATOR ' }, { '
                           )
              ,' } ]'
             )
  FROM (SELECT a1.title
              ,a1.content
              ,CONCAT( '[ { '
                      ,GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'author: "', REPLACE( c.author, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                            ,', message: "', REPLACE( c.message, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                           )
                                     SEPARATOR ' }, { '
                                   )
                      ,' } ]'
                     ) as comments
          FROM articles a1
          LEFT OUTER
          JOIN comments c
            ON c.articleId = a1.articleId
         GROUP BY a1.title, a1.content
       ) a
;
```

This will need some tweaking as strings get large. Would probably be best to return one row per article:

```
SELECT a1.title
      ,a1.content
      ,CONCAT( '[ { '
              ,GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'author: "', REPLACE( c.author, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                    ,', message: "', REPLACE( c.message, '"', '\"' ), '"'
                                   )
                             SEPARATOR ' }, { '
                           )
              ,' } ]'
             ) as comments
  FROM articles a1
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN comments c
    ON c.articleId = a1.articleId
 GROUP BY a1.title, a1.content
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edcd/13

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is correct if both queries are done within the same transaction. It basically trades CPU-time on the server-side (for the costly second query) for some CPU-time on the client-side and network traffic in between.

While the second approach at first seems costly on the network-traffic side, some on-the-wire protocols support referring to same-value columns in an efficient way. Column values repeated due to joins are not transmitted for every row in that case. You should check how much traffic is really generated, the overhead is probably not as large as it seems.
On the client side, you can store all `articles` in a hashmap-like-object, using the `article`'s primary key. While receiving rows, you add comments to a list, each listed being indexed by that key. This can be made more efficient by sorting the rows on the server-side according to `article`'s primary key, enabling you to use a naturally sorted list of lists on the client. Building this structure is the cpu-time-tradeoff compared to the first approach.
My verdict: Use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent function of the PostgreSQL's json_agg functiun is on the agenda of the next release of MySQL.

That will be very helpful.

You can check that at (there is a tip to realize the same kind of result with the current versions) :

[MySQL 8.0 Labs: JSON aggregation functions(to follow)](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-json-aggregation-functions/)