# geojson from mysql : convert a postgresql's query with aggregation function json_agg (for web mapping)

Tags: php, mysql, json, geojson, aggregation

One question regarding MySQL and GeoJSON aggregation functions:

I would like convert a query from PostgreSQL to a MySQL 5.7 query according to the tip at the end of the following article

[MySQL 8.0 Labs: JSON aggregation functions](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-json-aggregation-functions/)

Or this solution for MySQL with an equivalent method in postgresql:
[Construct nested object graph from SQL hasmany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726726/construct-nested-object-graph-from-sql-hasmany-relationship/47464616#47464616)

I have already find the main functions for MySQL 8.0

The query to convert with the tip explained at the end of the article:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs',  JSON_OBJECT(
        'type',      'name',
        'properties', JSON_OBJECT(
        'name', 'EPSG:4326')),
    'features', **JSON_OBJECTAGG**(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'type',       'Feature',
            'id',         site.id_site,
            'geometry',    ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom),
            'properties', JSON_OBJECT(
            'name', 'name',
            'espece', espece_name,
            'pseudo', pseudo
            )
        )
    )
) AS objet_geosjon FROM site, catch, fish, espece, hunting_party WHERE site.id_site = catch.id_site AND catch.id_fish = fish.id_fish AND fish.id_espece = fish.id_espece AND catch.id_hunting_party = hunting_party.id_hunting_party;
```

The structure needed in geojson:
{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "crs" : {"type" : "name", "properties" : {"name" : "EPSG:4326"}}, "features" : [{"type" : "Feature", "id" : 1, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.59004219507089,48.559968224588]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "dorade royale", "pseudo" : "Fred"}}, {"type" : "Feature", "id" : 2, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.5891116804469,48.559135011761]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "dorade royale", "pseudo" : "Fred"}}, {"type" : "Feature", "id" : 4, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.58834537428597,48.5601855821988]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "congre", "pseudo" : "Fred"}}, {"type" : "Feature", "id" : 3, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.58642960888365,48.5594972798939]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "dorade royale", "pseudo" : "Joe"}}, {"type" : "Feature", "id" : 5, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.58708644273588,48.5570338054289]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "sole commune", "pseudo" : "Joe"}}, {"type" : "Feature", "id" : 6, "geometry" : {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.5890022081382,48.5594610531973]}, "properties" : {"name" : "name", "espece" : "congre", "pseudo" : "Fred"}}]}

Thank you.

I found a way in php :

```
<?php include("connection_db_mysql.php");if($dbconn){/*Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element*/ $sql =
SELECT espece_name as espece, pseudo,  ST_ASGEOJSON(the_geom) AS geojson FROM site,  catch, fish, espece, hunting_party WHERE site.id_site = catch.id_site AND catch.id_fish = fish.id_fish AND fish.id_espece = espece.id_espece AND catch.id_hunting_party = hunting_party.id_hunting_party;';

# Try query or error
$rs = $dbconn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}



$prop = array('name' =>  'EPSG:4326' );
//$crs = array('type' => 'name' , 'properties' => json_encode($prop, JSON_HEX_QUOT)); 
//$crs = array('type' => 'name' , 'properties' =>  htmlspecialchars(json_encode($prop), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'crs'    => 'to_replace',
   // 'crs' => htmlspecialchars(json_encode($crs), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
   'features'  => array()
);
//


//'{"type" : "name", "properties" : {"name" : "EPSG:4326"}}'

//array_push($crs['properties'], $prop);
//array_push($objet_geojson['crs'], $crs);
$i=1;
# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    # Remove geojson and geometry fields from properties
    unset($properties['geojson']);
    unset($properties['the_geom']);
    $feature = array(
         'type' => 'Feature',
         'id' => $i,
         'geometry' => json_decode($row['geojson'], true),
         'properties' => $properties
    );
    $i++;
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
$objet_geojson=str_replace('"to_replace"','{"type" : "name", "properties" : {"name" : "EPSG:4326"}}', json_encode($geojson))}
```

?>

Sure it's durt ;)